# non exhaustive pattern in function filtering?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

```
cubes = [ (a,b,c) | a <- [1..30],b <-[1..30],c <- [1..30] ]

filtering (d,f,g)
 | d == f && f == g && d ==g = "cube"

third = filter newfun cubes 

newfun (x,y,z) = (filtering (x,y,z) == "cube")



*Charana> third
[(1,1,1)*** Exception: haskell.hs:(55,1)-(56,37): Non-exhaustive patterns in  function filtering
```

So when i put this in terminal it gives me a `non-exhaustive pattern error` ,the functions individually by them selves works fine and the program complies fine too.Any idea? 
Thank you

Comment: what is `filtering` supposed to do if f,d,g are *not* all the same?

Comment: No, no, no .... `filtering ("foo", "bar", "baz")`  does not work fine ....

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
cubes = [ (a,b,c) | a <- [1..30],b <-[1..30],c <- [1..30] ]

filtering (d,f,g) = d == f && f == g && d == g

third = filter filtering cubes
```

Some comments:

Do you really need to check `d == g`? I'd expect it to follow by transitivity from the other two equality checks.

It is customary to add type annotations to top-level definitions. I'd suggest e.g.

```
cubes :: [(Int,Int,Int)]
cubes = [ (a,b,c) | a <- [1..30],b <-[1..30],c <- [1..30] ]

filtering :: (Int,Int,Int) -> Bool
filtering (d,f,g) = d == f && f == g && d == g

third :: [(Int,Int,Int)]
third = filter filtering cubes
```

Always compile your code with warning enabled. E.g. use this at the top of your file

```
{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}
```

or pass the `-Wall` flag manually to GHC. If you do, it will warn you about functions being potentially non-exhaustive at compile time. For instance,

```
someFunction x
   | someConditionOn x = someValue
```

will trigger the warning since it does not say what should be the result when `someConditionOn x` is false.

Comment: The one warning that drives me crazy is the name shadowing one. If I shadow a global name, I almost certainly don't care. And if I shadow a local one, it's probably intentional--I can use shadowing to guarantee I won't accidentally reuse the initial value of a loop variable.